# How to count reads in bam per bed interval with bedtools

Tags: sam, bedtools

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 (because I was still using 12.04). But it seems my bedtools scripts don't work properly anymore. I can't figure out how to use the new bedtools for my old ways. What I want to do is get the number of reads from a bam file, per interval from a bed file. It was very simple with my old version of Ubuntu and bedtools:

```
bedtools coverage -abam file.bam -b All_peaks.bed > file.cov.txt
```

But this doesn't seem to work anymore. I used to get small files as results (~3MB), but now huge files are created (~4GB) including read names??

I am using bedtools v2.25 now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order of `-a` and `-b` switched at some point. You want:

```
bedtools coverage -a All_peaks.bed -b file.bam > file.cov.txt
```

For reference, this is the end of the help output in version 2.25:

```
Default Output:  
     After each entry in A, reports: 
       1) The number of features in B that overlapped the A interval.
       2) The number of bases in A that had non-zero coverage.
       3) The length of the entry in A.
       4) The fraction of bases in A that had non-zero coverage.
```

And this is the equivalent output from version 2.19:

```
Default Output:  
     After each entry in B, reports: 
       1) The number of features in A that overlapped the B interval.
       2) The number of bases in B that had non-zero coverage.
       3) The length of the entry in B.
       4) The fraction of bases in B that had non-zero coverage.
```

**Update**: The change in behavior happened in version 2.24:

> We have changed the behavior of the coverage tool such that it is consistent with the other tools. Specifically, coverage is now
>   computed for the intervals in the A file based on the overlaps with the B file, rather than vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Devon! I wasn't aware of the 'switch'. Switching -a and -b solves indeed my problem!